# PHP: most efficient way of structuring IF clauses

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm looking at a way of structuring `if` clauses using the DRY principles of Don't Repeat Yourself.

This is work involving scripts that are ~15 years old and poorly coded with globals etc., and I'm asked to drag this script/site into the 21st Century - but due to time and cost constraints, I can not facilitate a complete site rewrite from scratch, although I know that would be *far* better.

I have a value that is formerly a global value and I do not know where it comes from and it may come from different places from different pages.

I have some activity that is checking an input value in `$_POST` or `$_GET` data, if the input value is empty (or invalid), then check if the value is in fact sat in a `$_SESSION`. If the input value is *still* empty (or invalid) then boot to another page.

My code as it stands:

```
$userId = $_REQUEST['userid'];
if (empty($userId)) {
    $userId = $_SESSION['userid'];
    }
if(empty($userId) || !is_numeric($userId))
    {
    header("Location:contactdetails.php");
    die();
    }
```

I repeat the `empty()` function twice, I could wrap both IF's into one line but then would need an IF to pass the value from the `REQUEST` or the `SESSION` into the `$userId` variable.

Is there a (better) way that I can check the two possible inputs to see where this [formerly global] '['userid']' variable is coming from and applying that value to the page-local `userId` variable?

Comment: What is your target version of PHP?

Comment: formerly php version 4, now the target php version is 5.5.17

Comment: If it can come from multiple spots (all being valid) wouldn't it be more efficient to coalesce it in one line?

Comment: Sometimes it cannot be helped, but something smells fishy on this code anyway. Why are you trusting `$userId` from the client? It looks like something that should be kept internal, since you are envolving `$_SESSION['userid']` on the thing.

Comment: @BradChristie that is what I'm asking, can I do that while still preserving which incoming variable (`SESSION` or `REQUEST`) is sending the value? REQUEST variables trump SESSION variables as far as I can tell with the code

Comment: @Havenard - yes, the code is terrible. The original author passed userids in POST forms and with GET appends to pages, some later pages have data saved in sessions (pages made around 2005 onwards) but still, I am unable to rewrite the whole site, but need to find a way of make each page work well enough until I can get the job of completely rewriting it!

Comment: Also, you should check if `$_REQUEST['userid']` was declared before trying to use it. By doing `$userId = $_REQUEST['userid']` without checking if `$_REQUEST['userid']` was declared at all, you will set `$userId` to `null` and possibly throw a `Notice`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). The first expression will be used if it evaluates to true, otherwise the latter one. The `$_REQUEST` superglobal takes precedence in this case, like the code in the question:

```
$userId = $_REQUEST['userid'] ?: $_SESSION['userid'];
if (empty($userId) || !is_numeric($userId)) {
    header("Location:contactdetails.php");
    exit;
}
```

However as Havenard stated in a comment above, blindly trusting request data could be a security issue.

Also note that the condition will be true if any user IDs are `0`, in that case a `null` check would be better:

```
$userId = $_REQUEST['userid'] ?: $_SESSION['userid'];
if ($userId === null || !is_numeric($userId)) {
    header("Location:contactdetails.php");
    exit;
}
```

Of course this is assuming that you do not store falsy values in the `$_SESSION` as a non-null value.

Comment: This looks like what I have been looking for, thank you. In reply to your statement on trust, yes, I agree entirely but I use the `is_numeric` function to try and limit the risks here.

Comment: @Martin Do note that `is_numeric` allows you to enter numbers in other forms such as hexadecimal and scientific notation. `ctype_digit` might be better for this case.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on that, I will put that in place.

Comment: this will generate E_NOTICE if `$_REQUEST['userid']` not set

Comment: Hope you'll never have a userId == 0, my client have (too bad, I know).

Comment: @venca Yes, however the OP did not indicate that an E_NOTICE would be an issue.

Comment: @Armage In that case the original code would have failed too so I would assume that a 0 or "0" is not expected, however I have appended my answer to address that.

Answer (score 3):

If `$_SESSION['userid']` is guaranteed to be set, [rink.attendant.6's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739261/156811) seem like a clean approach. Otherwise, you will have to perform the necessary checks for both `$_REQUEST` and `$_SESSION` to guarantee that `$userId` is set properly:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['userid']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['userid']))
    $userId = $_REQUEST['userid'];
else if (isset($_SESSION['userid']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['userid']))
    $userId = $_SESSION['userid'];
else // no acceptable value for $userId in sight
{
    header("Location: contactdetails.php");
    exit;
}
```

You might want to reconsider using `is_numeric()` also, since it validates as `true` for numeric representations in any format, not just positive integers as you might expect.

Comment: The primary input for the values will be a `GET` or `POST` , the `SESSION` data would be only on a few pages.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different problems you're solving here.  First is the problem of *defaulting* and second is *filtering*.  Take each in turn.

For defaulting, you can implement a simple "get from array if it exists otherwise default" helper:

```
function array_get(array $a, $key, $default = null) {
    return (array_key_exists($key, $a) ? $a[$key] : $default);
}
```

You can then use this helper to provide default chaining:

```
$userId = array_get($_REQUEST, 'userid', $_SESSION['userid']);
```

For filtering, you know from this chain that you've got either a null or a value from one of the two arrays.  Since you're looking for ostensibly a database ID, I like a function like this:

```
function is_id_like($it) {
    $rc = filter_var($it, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array ('options' => array (
        'default' => false, 'min_range' => 1,
    )));
   return (false === $rc ? false : true);
}
```

This ensures that the number you give it looks like an int, is 1 or higher, and will return `false` if not.  So all these pass: `1`, `"1"`, and `"1.0"` but these all fail: `0` and `"1.1"`.

---

Combining these, and allowing for the session to not have a user ID:

```
$userId = array_get($_REQUEST, 'userid', array_get($_SESSION, 'userid'));
if (! is_id_like($userId)) {
    header('Location: contactdetails.php');
    die();
}
```

The total number of checks has changed to one `array_key_exists` and one `filter_var`, but the code is substantially more readable and these methods can be reused throughout your code base.

Answer (score 0):

If the value will only ever be set in either the request or session then concat the possible values and validate once.

Comment: Based on the wording, it looks like its possible for1 or more locations to contain a valid value, each having its own precedence.

Answer (score -2):

You should be using if-else for two-way statements and using a switch for n-way statements.

```
swicth($myVar){
case 1: doX();break;
case 'a': doY();break;
case 2: doZ();break;
default: doA();
}
```